# For-loop with string possible?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I need something like this. Is it possible in Java?

```
    for(String i = "A"; i < "Z"; i++) {

        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by:

```
for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
    System.out.println(alphabet);
}
```